# How do I use snakeyaml as a function that returns something?

Tags: java, yaml, snakeyaml

I am trying to make a function with snakeyaml that dumps an int, a string, and a string[]. The thing is I don't know how to write the function so that the info can be inserted.

For example:

```
public void testDump() {
    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("name", "Silenthand Olleander");
    data.put("race", "Human");
    data.put("traits", new String[] { "ONE_HAND", "ONE_EYE" });
    Yaml yaml = new Yaml();
    String output = yaml.dump(data);
    System.out.println(output);
}
```

I need things like `"name"` and `"Silenthand Olleander"` to be configurable. I also dont know exactly what this function does. Does it create a new file? Because I need it to add a line to an existing strings.yml file. So I would like the format of string.yml to be like this:

```
#String.yml file
0 name_here The array of argument messages here.
1 name_here Another array of argument messages here.
2 name_here And again... I think you get the point.
```

Answer (score 0):

As the code (ultimately) comes from the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/snakeyaml/wiki/Documentation#Dumping_YAML), I assume you have read that.

The call `yaml.dump()` does not create a file, rather returns a string (which you can then [put into a file](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html)).  According to the documentation, the `dump` method will handle lists/arrays properly.

To make the keys in your HashTable (e.g. "name") configurable, you can pass the required value to the function that populates the table.

Based on your questions, though it seems you need a crash-course in how to program in Java itself, before you should tackle snakeyaml.

Comment: I think its the Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>(); that confuses me. I know enough Java to do what I'm doing aside from this YAML. I also dont have much experience with reading documentations or other people's code.

Comment: You should get into the habit of reading documentation: it can save you the trouble from (seemingly) random errors down the road.  As for the HashMap, do what is the source of your confusion?